# Driver is not compiling "No rule to make target"

Tags: makefile

- Compile this driver with:

  echo "obj-m := tiny_i2c_adap.o" > Makefile
  make -C  SUBDIRS=$PWD modules

Makefile:
  obj-m := tiny_i2c_adap.o

Error :
prashanth@prashanth-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~$ make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) M=$PWD modules
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.1.7-050107-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/prashanth/tiny_i2c_adap.c', needed by '/home/prashanth/tiny_i2c_adap.o'.  Stop.
Makefile:1571: recipe for target '*module*/home/prashanth' failed
make: *** [*module*/home/prashanth] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.1.7-050107-generic'

Comment: You are intended to execute that build command from the directory containing the C source file (`tiny_i2c_adap.c`).  You are not doing so.

Comment: After you post your question, you should re-read it to make sure it's clear.  When you do that you will notice that the formatting of your question is all messed up making it unreadable.  You should then proceed to edit it to correct the formatting: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Of course better would be to notice that the formatting was all messed up and the question was unreadable _before_ you posted it, by checking the preview of your question right below the entry text box :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember `$PWD` is a *shell* variable, which contains the current working directory.  So when you run:

```
~$ make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) M=$PWD modules
```

the value of `$PWD` here is the directory you are in when you run make (in this case your home directory) so you're running:

```
~$ make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) M=/home/prashanth modules
```

So the kernel makefile assumes that your module lives in `/home/prashanth` because that's where you set the `M` variable to.

You need to either use the correct path for `M`, or else use `cd` to switch to the directory containing your source before invoking `make` so that `$PWD` will contain the right path.